# Limit of products of differences of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

My first post here, hope doing everything the right way.

I'm struggling with the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(3^x-x)\left[\ln(x^4+1)-2\ln(x^2-x)\right]$$

First of all I used logarithm properties to transform the function in the form
$$\ln(3^x-x)\ln\bigg(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\bigg)$$
Here I noticed that the first logarithm goes to infinity for $x$ that goes to infinity
and the second goes to zero because the argument goes to $1$ for $x$ to infinity.
So it is an undefined form $0\cdot\infty$.

Next I tried to use algebraic transformations and known limits but I can't find anything useful to solve the limit because every try ends up in another undefined form.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: The first logarithm behaves like $x\ln 3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- $\ln\bigg(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\bigg)=\ln\bigg(1+\frac{2x^3-x^2+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\bigg)$
- $\ln(3^x-x) =\ln 3^x+\ln\left(1-\frac x{3^x}\right) =x\ln
     3+\ln\left(1-\frac x{3^x}\right)$

then

$$\ln(3^x-x)\ln\bigg(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\bigg)=$$

$$=\frac{\left(x\ln 3+\ln\left(1-\frac x{3^x}\right)\right)\left(2x^3-x^2+1\right)}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\cdot\frac{\ln\bigg(1+\frac{2x^3-x^2+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\bigg)}{\frac{2x^3-x^2+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}}\to 2\ln 3\cdot 1=2\ln 3$$

Answer (score 1):

You have
\begin{multline}
\ln\left(3^x-x\right)\ln\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)=\\
=\ln\left(3^x\right)\ln\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{3^x-x}{3^x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right).
\end{multline}
Clearly, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3^x-x}{3^x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)=0$. On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(3^x\right)\ln\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)=\ln(3)\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)^x\right).
$$
Now, note that
$$
\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}=1+\frac2x+\frac1{x^2}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}
$$
and that therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)^x=e^2.
$$
So,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^4-2x^3+x^2}\right)^x\right)=2,
$$
and you can deduce from this that your limit is equal to $2\ln(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can break down each logarithm into simpler pieces using taylor expansion (this is usually the go-to method as it works all the time and it helps to understand each term's bevahior) :

$$ \ln(3^x-x) = \ln(3^x(1-\frac{x}{3^x})) = x\ln(3)+\ln(1-\frac{x}{3^x}) =  x\ln(3)+o(1)$$

$$ \ln(1+x^4) = \ln(x^4(1+\frac{1}{x^4})) = 4 \ln(x) + \frac{1}{x^4} + o(\frac{1}{x^4}) $$

$$ \ln(x^2-x) = \ln(x^2(1-\frac{1}{x})) = 2\ln(x) -\frac{1}{x} + o(\frac{1}{x})$$

Where we used $\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)(u \to 0)$ the first order taylor expansion of the logarithm. Also note that $o(1)$ simply means that this is an expression that goes to $0$.

Then
\begin{align}
\ln(3^x-x)\left[\ln(x^4+1)-2\ln(x^2-x)\right] &= (x \ln(3)+o(1))(4\ln(x)-4\ln(x)+\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{2}{x} + o(\frac{1}{x})) \\
&= \ln(3)(\frac{1}{x^3}+2 ) + o(1) \\
&\to_{x \to + \infty} 2\ln(3)
\end{align}

Note that $o(\frac1{x})+o(\frac1{x^4}) = o(\frac1{x})$ which is why $o(\frac1{x^4})$ disappeared.

Also note the cancellation of $4\ln(x) - 4 \ln(x)$ which leads to the undefined form, however using the first order terms we manage to deal with it.